# Error while running ARA server on Alpine linux

Tags: ansible, alpine-linux, ara

I am trying to install the latest version of the Ansible Records Analyzer server on an alpine Linux I made sure that all requirements are well installed ( Django, GCC,python3, Pypi, ansible) the install went well except for a warning about the absence of root PATH on the PATH variable which I fixed:
The warning :

```
  WARNING: The script pbr is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

The fix:

```
~ # export PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
```

So following the install [guide](https://ara.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html) on this step that intends to run the server I have an avalanche of errors as if the run command doesn't find the needed components to be executed although I'm sure all the components are installed :

```sh
~ # ara-manage runserver
[ara] No setting found for SECRET_KEY. Generating a random key...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/bin/ara-manage", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ara/server/__main__.py", line 41, in main
    if not os.path.exists(settings.ARA_SETTINGS):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ara/server/settings.py", line 263, in <module>
    ALLOWED_HOSTS=ALLOWED_HOSTS.to_list(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_list'
```

What could be the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to overcome this issue, the problem was in dynaconf the current version 3.1.3 doesn't read the conf files properly which fails in the server run.

Meanwhile, the only workaround is to install the previous version of dynaconf :

```
pip install 'dynaconf==3.1.2'
```

FYI dynaconf already has a fix proposed for the regression: [rochacbruno/dynaconf#541](https://github.com/rochacbruno/dynaconf/pull/541)

I've tested that it does resolve this issue and it will be released in dynaconf 3.1.4 soon.